# Executing a binary gem file with unpacked gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using the gem whenever

To update the crontab, it executes the whenever command in the root directory of my application.

The trouble is: my production environment doesn't have the gem installed, so I unpacked the whenever gem into my application and running 'whenever' from my application root directory fails to find the file

How do I run the frozen gem executable from the root directory of my application?

I found that

```
cd #{release_path} && /usr/bin/ruby #{release_path}/script/runner #{release_path}/vendor/gems/whenever-0.4.1/bin/whenever --update-crontab #{application}
```

works; but this seems like the 'wrong' answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has the answer you're looking for:
http://www.mail-archive.com/rubyonrails-talk@googlegroups.com/msg45169.html

> Finally, you usually can add gems to
>   the load path by doing the following
>   within your environment.rb:
>
> Option 1:  add gems using less ruby
>   code within the environment.rb file
>
> # Add additional load paths for your
>   own custom dirs   config.load_paths +=
>   %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/extras )
>
> Option 2:   add gems using more ruby
>   code within the environment.rb file
>
> Dir.glob( File.expand_path(
>   "#{RAILS_ROOT}/vendor/gems/*",
>   **FILE**) ).each do | gem |
>       $:.unshift File.join( gem, 'lib' )   end
>
> Option 3:  using a combination of
>   Option (1) and (2).

Read the whole message, it's quite instructive.